# Select query for dynamic Table Name in oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried the following code:

```
declare
selectedtable varchar2(50);
tablename varchar2(50);
begin
selectedtable := 'ATABLE';
SELECT table_name into tablename FROM all_tables where table_name = selectedtable;
select * from tablename;
end;
```

But I got "Table or View does not exist."

Comment: What output are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

It can't work that way because

- `tablename` is *unknown*; Oracle "thinks" it is a table name (real table name, available to you)
- `select * from ...` is invalid in PL/SQL - it requires an `INTO` clause. Moreover, unless it returns exactly one row, you'll get either no_data_found or too_many_rows error

What you *could* do, is to use `tablename` variable in a ref cursor.

Let's presume that `tablename` now contains table name retrieved from `all_tables`; though, *why* would you want to do that? You already have that name in `selectedtable` variable ... Also, if there are two (or more) tables that share that name - as you're selecting from `all_tables` - you'll get too_many_rows error - hence, I used the `distinct` keyword. If there's no such table, your query will return no_data_found you didn't handle. But OK, let's suppose that table in `selectedtable` exists.

Then:

```
SQL> declare
  2    selectedtable varchar2(50);
  3    tablename varchar2(50);
  4    --
  5    -- Some new local variables
  6    rc sys_refcursor;
  7    l_deptno number;
  8    l_dname  varchar2(20);
  9    l_loc    varchar2(20);
 10  begin
 11    selectedtable := 'DEPT';
 12    SELECT distinct table_name into tablename FROM all_tables where table_name = selectedtable;
 13
 14    open rc for 'select * from ' || tablename;
 15    loop
 16      fetch rc into l_deptno, l_dname, l_loc;
 17      exit when rc%notfound;
 18      dbms_output.put_line('Fetched: ' || l_deptno ||', '|| l_dname ||', '|| l_loc);
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
Fetched: 10, ACCOUNTING, NEW YORK
Fetched: 20, RESEARCH, DALLAS
Fetched: 30, SALES, CHICAGO
Fetched: 40, OPERATIONS, BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```